# java - How to add special character in enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem here. I created SpecialCharacterField.java - an enum class that will list some special characters.

**`SpecialCharacterField.java`**

```
package bp.enumfield;

public enum SpecialCharacterField {
   +, #;
}
```

In my eclipse on the line : `public enum SpecialCharacterField{` there is an error it says:      `Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant.Have a look at this http://www.coderanch.com/t/515142/java/java/Including-sign-Enum

Comment: You may want to look at my answer too. It differs from the currently "Accepted" one in an important way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

do something like this,

```
public enum SpecialCharacterField{
   PLUS("+"),
   HASH("#");

   private String value;
   private SpecialCharacterField(String value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return this.value; //This will return , # or +
   }
}
```

Comment: You beat me by ten seconds with pretty much exactly the same code I wrote.  :-)

Comment: @Lion, in the answer that I wrote and then deleted because it was redundant.

Comment: This isn't a good solution, and the comment is wrong - toString doesn't return `HASH` etc, it returns `"#"`

Answer (score 5):

Those characters cannot be parts of identifiers in the Java language. Note that the JVM itself imposes no such restrictions (only ./; and [ are prevented), so you could use names like that if you wrote bytecode directly. However this is usually not a desirable approach.

Answer (score 3):

enums can have fields and getter just like regular classes.

```
public enum SpecialCharacterField{
   Plus('+'),
   Hash('#');

   private final char character;
   private SpecialCharacterField(char character) {
      this.character = character;
   }

   public char getCharacter() {
      return character;
   }
}
```

**Note:** Avoid overriding `toString()` - doing so is an anti-pattern: `toString()` is for "human eyes only" - it shouldn't be relied upon in code.